# How to set a really wide home screen that scrolls

Tags: launcher, wallpaper

How do I set a really wide home screen as the home screen that as you swipe from page to page the background scrolls with it.

I swear it used to do this or I'm imagining it did.

Samsung Galaxy S6, Android 5.1.1 that came with the phone.

Comment: Did you try the Nova launcher? It's a setting that depends upon your launcher.

Comment: I just checked, and Nova allows you to set a wallpaper that gets scrolled whenever you swipe through your home screen. It can disable the scrolling, enable it, make it scroll in a reversed fashion, and force it on devices that doesn't support the feature.

Comment: Which launcher are you using? The settings aren't the same for all, that's why I suggested editing.

Comment: I haven't changed anything since I got it. No rooting, no custom anything. I added my phone info.

Answer (score -1):

**OPTION A**

1. Pinch to zoom out on home screen.
2. Tap on rectangle with PLUS sign. (Located furthest to right).
3. Add as many as need. (There is a limit of 10 - S6 Edge+).

**OPTION B**

1. Long press on blank area of home screen.
2. Follow steps 2 & 3 from Option A.

**OPTION C**

1. Access launcher settings.
2. Swipe left to access the home screen page.
3. Follow steps 2 & 3 from Option A.

*I didn't include any references as every site confirmed the information above. The list would be too large.*

---

Search keywords:

**add home screens to Samsung Galaxy S6**

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The request is about how to make a wide picture set as wallpaper scroll as you swipe through screens, but this answer talks about how to add more screens.